# How to use TLsharp API in C# to send a multi-line message?

Tags: c#, sharp

I want use Telegram API in C# for send a multi-line message to a channel. I use TLsharp but I am not able to send emoji and multi-line message.

Can anyone give me a code?

```
private async void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (client.IsUserAuthorized()) { MessageBox.Show("You Logined!"); };
            var dialogs = (TLDialogs)await client.GetUserDialogsAsync();
        var chat = dialogs.chats.lists
            .OfType<TLChannel>()
            .SingleOrDefault(a => a.title == "AliGol");
        await client.SendMessageAsync(new TLInputPeerChannel() { channel_id = chat.id, access_hash = chat.access_hash.Value }, "OUR_MESSAGE");
        var fileResult = await client.UploadFile("C:\\a\\ali.jpg", new StreamReader("data/ali.jpg"));
        await client.SendUploadedPhoto(new TLInputPeerChannel() { channel_id = chat.id, access_hash = chat.access_hash.Value }, fileResult, "MultiLine Message");


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

oh its pretty simple, just:

```
await client.SendUploadedPhoto(new TLInputPeerChannel() { channel_id = chat.id, access_hash = chat.access_hash.Value }, fileResult, "New line" + Environment.NewLine + "another line"); or             ("this is first line" + "\n" + "this is second line");
```